# How can I configure local (USB) printers when a remote cups server is specified (in client.conf)?

Tags: printing, cups-lpd, kerberos

In our organisation we have a central CUPS server (with Kerberos) for printing. On all Ubuntu clients this server is configured via the client.conf.

How can I add additional local printers (USB) to the system so I can print to both, the CUPS server and my local printers? How would I need to reconfigure my local cups setup?

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution to this problem.

1. We deleted the file /etc/cups/client.conf
2. We started & enabled the service cups-browsed and added the following stanza to  /etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf:

   BrowseRemoteProtocols cups dnssd

   BrowsePoll cups.myorganisation.com

   Browsing On